# Stubbing Time.now with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to stub Time.now in RSpec as follows:

```
it "should set the date to the current date" do
    @time_now = Time.now
    Time.stub!(:now).and_return(@time_now)

    @thing.capture_item("description")
    expect(@thing.items[0].date_captured).to eq(@time_now)
end
```

I am get the following error when doing so:

```
 Failure/Error: Time.stub!(:now).and_return(@time_now)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stub!' for Time:Class
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Just as it says. `Time` does not have a method called `stub!`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Depending on your version of RSpec you might want to use the newer syntax:

```
allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(@time_now)
```

See [RSpec Mocks 3.3](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this line must be in a 'before' block to work. It had no effect when I tested it inside of an 'it' block.

Comment: How can I mock `DateTime.now.in_time_zone`? I need to run the test on the first of the month, monday, hour 0.

Comment: Avoid using mocks or you will have hard time making any change in implementation.

Answer (score 14):

### You'd better use [`travel_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to) from `ActiveSupport`:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/testing/time_helpers'

Time.zone = 'UTC'

RSpec.describe 'Testing time' do
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

  it 'stubs current time' do
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('1970-01-01 08:00:30') do
      some_method_that_uses_current_time
    end
  end
end
```

Neither Rails nor other gems are needed.

Comment: Not quite working: `NoMethodError: undefined method `travel_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups...`  

You should include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers:

Comment: @AurelBranzeanu The example has been updated to work with plain Ruby and RSpec (as the tags of the question imply). The `include` has been added as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop). Freeze the time before the test and  unfreeze it after.

```
describe "some tests" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.now)
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it "should do something" do
  end
end
```

or define a specific time with

```
let(:time_now) { Time.now }
```

and used in `Timecop.freeze(time_now)` and in tests

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop):

```
@time_now = Time.now

Timecop.freeze(@time_now) do
  @thing.capture_item("description")
  expect(@thing.items[0].date_captured).to eq(@time_now)
end
```

Comment: or with a before block: `before { Timecop.freeze(Time.now) }`