# RSpec Stubbing out Date.today in order to test a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test a method that follows one path if the *current date* is between Jan 1st - Aug 1st, or it follows another path if the *current date* is between Aug 2nd - December 31st. example:

```
def return_something_based_on_current_date
  if date_between_jan_1_and_aug_1?
    return "foo"
  else 
    return "bar"
  end
end

private

def date_between_jan_1_and_aug_1?
  date_range = build_date_range_jan_1_through_aug_1
  date_range === Date.today
end

def build_date_range_jan_1_through_aug_1
  Date.today.beginning_of_year..Date.new(Date.today.year, 8, 1)
end
```

As you can see: `return_something_based_on_current_date` depends heavily upon `Date.today`, as does the private methods it invokes.  This is making it difficult to test both paths within this method since `Date.today` dynamically returns the current date.

For testing purposes: I need `Date.today` to return a static date that I want it to so that I can test that each path is working correctly.

- I need to test that the path works correctly if the current date is between Jan 1 - Aug 1
- I need to test that the path works correctly if the current date is after Aug 1st.

**Question**: Is there a way that I can make `Date.today` return a value that I make up within my spec?  After the specs that test the `return_something_based_on_current_date`: I want the dynamic implementation of `Date.today` to go back to its usual implementation.  I just need control over `Date.today` to test this method.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300446/stubbing-time-now-with-rspec

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215245/how-to-fake-time-now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your before `block`.

```
allow(Date).to receive(:today).and_return Date.new(2001,2,3)
```

I *think* it is not necessary to unstub.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you look at the Timecop gem, it allows to freeze the time at a given date.

On top of stubbing the current Time, it also allows to travel in time for a given test

https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

```
describe "some set of tests to mock" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(1990))
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

  it "should do blah blah blah" do
  end
end
```

**Update**

As Andy mentions in the comments, there is a helper method `travel_to` available since Rails 4.1

Reference is available here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html

Comment: The `travel_to` helpers added in Rails 4.1 make Timecop unnecessary in most cases. http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/rails-4-1-travel-to-test-helper/

Comment: @AndyWaite Thanks, first time I hear about it. I use Rails since ver 1, its easy to overlook this kind of features added to the framework. Ill add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach you might want to consider, that doesn't require any stubbing – change the public method to accept an argument for the current date.

Clarification:

Change `def return_something_based_on_current_date` to `def return_something_based_on_current_date(current_date)`, then change all instances of `Date.today` to `current_date`. You'll also need to pass `current_date` into the private methods.

Then in your tests, you can pass whatever you want as `current_date`.

Comment: could you provide an example?  I am not quite clear on what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation but I didn't want to install the gem. as I was interested in time intervals bigger than one day so I decided to do it this way

```
it 'Creates an event for tomorrow' do
  event = FactoryBot.create(:event, :tomorrow)
  expect(event.date.day).to eq (Time.now + 1.day).day
end

it 'Creates an event for the next week' do
  event = FactoryBot.create(:event, :next_week)
  expect(event.date.day).to eq (Time.now + 1.week).day
end

it 'Creates an event for the next month' do
  event = FactoryBot.create(:event, :next_month)
  expect(event.date.day).to eq (Time.now + 1.month).day
end
```

so I just tested the expected date, I am afraid that there is a specific time of the day that the test will be broken but I don't care

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 4.2 there's the `ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers` module that provides a straightforward way to do this:

```
travel_to(Time.parse("2019-01-19")) do
  # your code here
end
```