# Stubbing Time.zone.now in RSpec returns blank when called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I tried stubbing Time.zone.now and it seems to work up until it is called when storing the timestamp in an ActiveRecord field

In my RSpec file, I stub the method `Time.zone.now` as such:

```
current_time = Time.zone.now
zone_ = double(zone_)

allow(Time).to receive(:zone).and_return(zone_)
allow(zone_).to receive(:now).and_return(current_time)
```

When I call `binding.pry` after stubbing and check `Time.zone.now` I get a valid timestamp all the way up until it is called in the method I am testing. For some reason, it is blank. I use the timestamp to save it to a field in an ActiveRecord object I am creating. So, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: <My_Field> can't be blank
```

What is the best way to stub `Time.zone.now`?

Comment: I ended up install Rubocop and following this recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300636/12616769

Comment: FYI Rubocop and Timecop are different things.

Comment: Ah right. I meant to say Timecop hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap up the comments: the best way to stub Time in Rspec is not to do it manually.

You can use the [Timecop Gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop).